# Trustworthy Audio App Review Sites?

Tags: sound-design, iphone, music, composition

Hey Audio pals - in addition to forums and peers, are there sites that you trust most regarding reviews for sound design/audio/music apps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.musicradar.com/tech

and

http://www.soundonsound.com/

To me these have been the most neutral and most knowledgeable (i.e. the reviewers have actually studied the technological aspects and other similar products in the market and not just usability aspects to know what they're speaking of).

Although, I'm a bit vary of what you mean by "trustworthy". When it comes to audio/media product reviews, it's all subjective/opinions.

Comment: Thanks very much! I enjoy SOS, but haven't spent much time on Music Radar. I agree on the subjectivity of "trustworthiness." I'm just seeing what places folks here find to be their go-to consistent sites. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.soundonsound.com/

as mentioned,

http://mixonline.com/

http://designingsound.org/

For a more sound design specific opinion

http://createdigitalmusic.com/

As I think they have a good take on things. Not so... rigorous, but fun!

Answer (score 0):

GiveMeApps - http://www.givemeapps.com